# Blog recommendations for children's book writers

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, book, children

Any suggestions for blog websites for picture book writers. I am new in the field and I would like to find websites for writers of children's books. 
Thank you.

Comment: Questions that are potentially endless lists of links aren't a good for for this site; the purpose of a Stack Exchange site is to provide canonical answers to specific questions. Closing, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For middle-grade picture books, I recommend Inkygirl: http://inkygirl.com/

There is also the Kidlidchat chat-event on Twitter, where you can connect to other kidlit-writers and find their blogs: https://twitter.com/kidlitchat